# match parens but not the contents

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, regex-lookarounds

is there a succinct regex to match a pair of parens and a proceeding dot, but not the contents inside the parens. This is for syntax highlighting in `Sublime Text 2` using `R-Sublime`.

In the following example, I want to highlight (positive match) three characters: .()

```
 Obj[.(var)]
     ^^   ^     match only these three
```

Currently, I am using `\.\(.+\)`  which matches the characters I want, but also is matching the contents inside the parens (in the example, it is matching `.(var)`

Comment: if there a function (like a callback on the match) you can create where once you get your match can you not parse the resulting substring separating the `.(` and `)` and highlighting those?

Answer (score 1):

No, if a regex consumes any characters, it must consume them all in one continuous block.  Syntax highlighting frameworks get around that limitation by letting you define complex rules where you match the beginning and ending tokens, and then delegate to another rule (or set of rules) to handle whatever lies in between.  In Sublime Text you create these nested Scopes by defining [Begin-End Rules](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html#begin-end-rules).